# Get closer to the pdo error

Tags: php, pdo

I have an error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function upload_image() on a non-object in /data/home/.../.../.../.../upload_image.php on line 28'.
 The function upload_image()is in the image.func.php file and I can't find the error.
In the upload_image() function is also a thumbnail function ans a image handler function so I think there are quite a lot of possibilities where the error can be. I am trying to get more details from the error handling but I am not getting any more then this fatal error.

The upload_image function looks like this;

```
    class Images{ 
private $db;

public function __construct($database) {
$this->db = $database;
}

public function upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id) {
global $thumbs;
$image_name = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
$time       = time();

$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `images` VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$query->bindValue(1, $image_id);
$query->bindValue(2, $image_name);
$query->bindValue(3, $_SESSION['id']);
$query->bindValue(4, $album_id);
$query->bindValue(5, $time);
$query->bindValue(6, $image_ext);

try{

$query->execute();

$image_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
$image_file = $image_id.'.'.$image_ext;

move_uploaded_file($image_temp, 'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file);      

$thumbs->create_thumb('uploads/'.$album_id.'/', $image_file, 'uploads/thumbs/'.$album_id.'/');

$source_image = 'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file;;
$destination = 'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file;
$tn_w = 900;
$tn_h = 600;
$quality = 100;
$wmsource = 'watermark.png';    
   $this->image_handler($source_image,$destination,$tn_w,$tn_h,$quality,$wmsource);                                                                                             
}catch(PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Here I try to get closer to the error with the try and catch block.

The init.php looks like this;

```
session_start();
require 'connect/database.php';
require 'classes/users.php';
require 'classes/general.php';
require 'classes/album.func.php';
require 'classes/image.func.php';
require 'classes/thumb.func.php';
require 'classes/bcrypt.php';

error_reporting(1);

$users      = new Users($db);
$general    = new General();
$albums     = new Albums($db);
$Images     = new Images($db);
$bcrypt     = new Bcrypt(12);
$thumbs     = new Create_thumb();

$errors = array();

if ($general->logged_in() === true)  {
$user_id    = $_SESSION['id'];
$user       = $users->userdata($user_id);
}
```

With the error reporting standing on 1.

Are there more possibilities to get get closer to the error?
Thanks...

Comment: Where on the Earth you all get this error_reporting(1)? it have to be **error_reporting(E_ALL);** at the very least.

Comment: make your upload_image.php has included "image.func.php". use include_once or require_once

Comment: The error is telling you that the _object_ on which you are calling `upload_image()` is not an `Images` object like you expect it to be.  We don't see that code...  Somewhere down the line, you are probably calling `$Images->upload_image()`??

Comment: I think the error is the function call to the upload_image function and i think you should look there. Probably you have an error in the calling code.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly where to look, so the relevant file is upload_image.php, on line 28 you are trying to use something and that something is not an object, so you cannot $object->upload_image() on something that is not an object. On another note, error_reporting(-1) turns on all error reporting not error_reporting(1) which is the same as error_reporting(E_ERROR) so misses out warnings and notices

Comment: Thanks, stupid from my side...